# In which file on disk is "global environment variables" stored in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

After an unsuccessful upgrade of Jenkins and its plugins, we're trying to get it back to its previous state. One of the things that have gone missing is the environment variables under "Global Properties" in "Global Configuration":
[image]

I know that Jenkins stores its configuration on disk and we have a backup of most files, so my question is, where is the configuration file holding the environment variables located on the Jenkins server (running in Ubuntu)?

Comment: Have you tried asking on the Jenkins gitter channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be in your `${JENKINS_HOME}/config.xml`

```
  <globalNodeProperties>
    <hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty>
      <envVars serialization="custom">
        <unserializable-parents/>
        <tree-map>
          <default>
            <comparator class="hudson.util.CaseInsensitiveComparator"/>
          </default>
          <int>1</int>
          <string>key</string>
          <string>value</string>
        </tree-map>
      </envVars>
    </hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty>
```

However, I think you should review  [Upgrading to Jenkins 2.277.1
Configuration Form Modernization](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.277/#configuration-form-modernization) and J[ENKINS-64072 - Configure UI completely broken after upgrade to 2.264](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-64072). That's probably the likely culprit to your problem and steps to address.